# nested $and in $or causes Exception in pouchdb-find

Tags: typescript, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm trying to do a simple Query with the pouchdb-find plugin. (Variables are just examples)

```
let query = {
  selector: {
    $or: [{
        $and: [
          {country_code: 'DE'},
          {zip_code: '47228'}
        ]
      },{
        $and: [
          {country_code: 'UK'},
          {zip_code: '45664'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

If im trying to nest $and in an $or like this, I'm always getting the following Exception:

```
Error: unknown operator "0" - should be one of $eq, $lte, $lt, $gt, $gte, $exists, $ne, $in, $nin, $size, $mod, $regex, $elemMatch, $type, $allMatch or $all
```

I did not find any solution to this or similar problems. Is this just not possible?
Nesting this the other way around ($or in $and) is working fine.
I just can't get my head around how to query for different Objects with specific sets of Attributes. The only solution I'm seeing at the moment is to do multiple queries.

Comment: Can you share more details about the context? From my tests, the query works fine either on CouchDB nor PouchDB side

Comment: @AlexisCôté im a bit confused about the 'nor' does the query work for you or does it not? (Will provide more about the environment when im back at work)

Comment: Sorry, it works on Couch and/or PouchDB

Comment: I can confirm that the query you supply works on Cloudant too.

Comment: @AlexisCôté we used PouchDB 6.3.4 with PouchDB-find 6.3.4.. we did not find a Solution to this Problem and implemented our own 'Filter' like the map-reduce examples in the PouchDB Documenation. We found that it may be an issue with the query building itself, because elements of an array  (like the $and) are merged into properties of an object when the query is build. -> the Queries are overriden always with the last query of the same name